# MIPS: Translating C code to MIPS problem in function calls and returns

Tags: c, mips, procedure, code-translation

I need to change C code from below to a MIPS code but I am new to MIPS and stuck with it.

Here is the C code:

```c
int main()
{
    int a, b, result;
    if(a == b)
         result = a*b;
    else
         result = assess(a, b);
    return result;
}

int assess(int a, int b)
{
    if(b<a)
        return upgrade(a, b);
    else
        return demote(a, b);
}

int upgrade(int a, int b)
{
    return 4*(a+b);
}

int demote(int a, int b)
{
    return 4*(b-a);
}
```

Here is MIPS code that I wrote, which isn't working (I am aware there are major errors and wrongs). Because I am not familiar with the language, my main problems are using stack, return and calling the functions.

```
.data
    a:.word 8
    b:.word 8
    result:.word 0
main:
    li $s0 a
    li $s1 b
    li $s3 result
    beq $s0,$s1,Resultmul ELSE
    add $s3,$s3,assess

assess:
    blt $s1,$s0,upgrade
    bge $s1,$0,demote
Resultmul :
    mul $s3,$s1,$0

upgrade:
    addi $sp,$sp,-4
    sw $0,0($sp)
    add $t1,$a0,$a1
    mul $t1,$t1,4
    add $v0,$s0,$zero
    lw $s0,0($sp)
    addi $sp,$sp,4
    jr $ra
demote:
    addi $sp,$sp,-4
    sw $0,0($sp)
    sub $t1,$a0,$a1
    mul $t1,$t1,4
    add $v0,$s0,$zero
    lw $s0,0($sp)
    addi $sp,$sp,4
    jr $ra
```

If someone can help that would be a lifesaver.

Comment: Does this actually assemble without errors?  What tool are you using?

Comment: Mars4_5 it assembles but doesn't run as expected and when assembled text segment is empty.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @ErikEidt it must be  result : .word 0  not equal my bad

Comment: Sometimes, it helps to see what a compiler would do...  https://godbolt.org/z/gDh9Je

Comment: You're missing the `.text` directive, so it is ignoring the whole program!  I have to say that is pretty odd behavior on MARS' part.  Put `.text` after your data and before the code.

Comment: @ErikEidt yes you are right i changed few things now still got many errors.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan actually i don't understand that compiler its my third day with MIPS so ı am not good with the language

Comment: FYI - your C code is using undefined behavior.  `a` and `b` in main() both need to have a value of some sort for things to work correctly.  I used `volatile` on them to tell the compiler to read garbage and got better code for next time.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan we will try the code with values a=8 b=8 a=3 b=5 a=5 b=3 you can assume it is 8 for both i did in my MISP code

Comment: I see it.  Got it.

Comment: no one got a fix for this ?

Comment: By convention, we use ````jr $ra```` after having called ````jal foo````. I can't find a ````jal```` here... It has been a while, and I'm seeing some things I'm not sure of are possible, but I'll try to do it my way. Also, ````b```` (branch) is being highlighted when rewriting your code; meaning it's recognized as an instruction - which probably causes other unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to give you the full solution, so you can learn from the exercise, but I recommend you work from a template, like at this one for example.

I used Visual Studio Code (with MIPS Support and Better MIPS support for highlighting), in which every whitespace or tab, gives me the possibility of collapsing it by these whitespaces, and QtSpim on which I was able to run this and got the output `64`.

Also, I'm used to coding with tabs; it's more clear to me, but it might not be to you, so I'm sorry if you have to remove all the tabs and comments.

```
######################## pseudo ####################################
 #
 #  int main()
 #  {
 #      int a, b, result;
 #      if(a == b)
 #           result = a*b;
 #      else
 #           result = assess(a, b);
 #      return result;
 #  }
 #  
 #  int assess(int a, int b)
 #  {
 #      if(b<a)
 #          return upgrade(a, b);
 #      else
 #          return demote(a, b);
 #  }
 #  
 #  int upgrade(int a, int b)
 #  {
 #      return 4*(a+b);
 #  }
 #  
 #  int demote(int a, int b)
 #  {
 #      return 4*(b-a);
 #  }
 #  
###################### DATA Segment ################################

    .data
 A:
    .word 8
 B:
    .word 8
 result:
    .word 0

###################### CODE Segment ################################

    .text
    .globl main
 main:
```

Here you made a little mistake: You already *stored* the words, so you should also *load* the words. Else, you'll have to type `li   $t0, 8`.

```
    # int A = A, B = B, result
    lw      $s0, A      # $s0 = A
    lw      $s1, B      # $s1 = B
    lw      $s2, result # $s2 = result    
    # if (a == b)
        bne     $s0, $s1, noteq # if $s0 != $s1 then noteq
        # result = multiply(a,b);
        move    $a0, $s0        # $a0 = $s0
        move    $a1, $s1        # $a1 = $s1
        jal     multiply        # jump to multiply and save position to $ra
        sw      $v0, result     #         
        b       end             # branch to end
    # else
        noteq:
        # result = assess(a,b);
        move    $a0, $s0        # $a0 = $s0
        move    $a1, $s1        # $a1 = $s1
        # jal       assess      # jump to assess and save position to $ra
        sw      $v0, result     #         
        b       end             # branch to end (this rule can be left out)
    end:
    # printf("%i", result)
    li      $v0, 1      # $v0 = 1
    lw      $a0, result #     
    syscall
    # exit()
    li      $v0, 10     # $v0 = 10
    syscall
```

Since they are functions in your pseudo-code, they should be treated as functions in your assembly as well. Meaning they are being called with `j` (for non-returning function like exit) or `jal` (and return with `jr`).

I made a completely unnecessary function `multiply` to show you the template, which is pretty handy for larger functions.

```
###################### FUNC Segment ################################

###################### FUNCTION ####################################
 # multiply(A, B)
 #
 # Purpose: <General description>
######################## i/0 #######################################
 # Input:
  # $a0 = A
  # $a1 = B
 # Output: 
  # $v0 = value
 # Registers being used:
  # $s0 = A
  # $s1 = B
  # $s2 = value
######################## pseudo ####################################
 #  
 #  int multiply(int A, int B)
 #  {
 #      return A * B;
 #  }
 #
######################## <code> ####################################
 multiply:#(A, B)
```

Always store the content of the registers you are going to overwrite, so you can call other functions without losing any content. Also immediately  initialize your parameters stored in `$a0-$a3` in new registers, because you might overwrite the parameters when printing something using `syscall`.

There are two main reasons to store the variables:

1. The function call want unknowingly change one of your `$s0-$s7`-registers.
2. Other functions can be called within the current function, with their own stack handling, so again no need to worry about registers. Might be interesting to know before making an `assess`-function.

This is how the initialization of a function's parameters would look like:

```
    # store(&return, parameters that are about overwritten)
    sub     $sp, $sp, 16    # $sp = $sp - 16
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)     #
    sw      $s0, 4($sp)     # 
    sw      $s1, 8($sp)     #
    sw      $s2, 12($sp)    # 
    # int A = A, B = B, value
    move    $s0, $a0        # $s0 = $a0
    move    $s1, $a1        # $s1 = $a1
```

This is the very short body of the function. As you can tell, storing all these parameters is idiotic, so don't make these overhead functions.

```
    # value = A * B;
    mul     $s2, $s0, $s1
```

This is to handle a function's return. In larger functions, you'll need a label most of the time to jump to the return-handling. I always call labels inside a function `foo` like `foo_thisLabel`, but that's just my recommendations.

```
    move    $v0, $s2        # $v0 = $s2
    # restore()
    lw      $ra, 0($sp)     #   
    lw      $s0, 4($sp)     # 
    lw      $s1, 8($sp)     # 
    lw      $s2, 12($sp)    #     
    addi    $sp, $sp, 12    # $sp = $sp + 12
    # return index
    jr      $ra             # jump to $ra
######################## </code> ###################################
```

Note that I only wait for the function's return segment to move `value` into the return register, `$v0`.

Here is an empty template for the other functions.

```
###################### FUNCTION ####################################
 # <name of function>
 #
 # Purpose: <General description>
######################## i/0 #######################################
 # Input:
  # $a0 = 
  # $a1 = 
  # $a2 = 
  # $a3 = 
 # Output: 
  # $v0 = 
 # Registers being used:
  # $t0 = 
  # $t1 = 
  # $t2 = 
  # $s0 = 
  # $s1 = 
  # $s2 = 
  # $s3 = 
  # $s4 = 
######################## pseudo ####################################
 #  
 #  int assess(int a, int b)
 #  {
 #      if(b<a)
 #          return upgrade(a, b);
 #      else
 #          return demote(a, b);
 #  }
 #
######################## <code> ####################################
 #
######################## </code> ###################################
```

P.S. I've renamed your variable names, because `b` might cause an error.